# XML Select Node into List Fail

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

No problems loading a simple XML file into a LIST.  BUT, when I create a second element it loads, but loads everything into one line.

I have even tried using xmlDoc.Descendants("apple") with the same results.

**Works.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<green_apple>
    <Location>CA</Location>
    <Price>.52</Price>
</green_apple>

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("apple.xml");
List<string> list = xmlDoc.Root.Elements()
                    .Select(element => element.Value.Trim())
                    .ToList();

List Result:
list[0] = CA
List[1] = .52
```

**Doesn't Work.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<apple>
    <green_apple>
        <Location>CA</Location>
        <Price>.52</Price>
    </green_apple>
    <red_apple>
        <Location>FL</Location>
        <Price>.71</Price>
    </red_apple>
</apple>

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("apple.xml");
            List<string> list = xmlDoc.Root.Elements("green_apple")   <<specify specify element.
                .Select(element => element.Value.Trim())
                .ToList();

List Result:
list[0] = CA.52   <<Here's the problem, they should be in their own list element.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Elements` retuns child elements of the current node, which in your case are `green_apple` elements. So you need to get `green_apple` child nodes by calling `Elements()` on `green_apple` element.

Use this:

```
List<string> list = xmlDoc.Root.Elements("green_apple").Elements()
                .Select(element => element.Value.Trim())
                .ToList();
```

Comment: @Kirill....you are the man.  Thank you.  I spent 2 hours and can't believe I missed the extra.Element().

Comment: @Pirate, sometimes it is nice to have an **extra** pair of eyes :)